# WiFi and data connection switches on automatically although I repeatedly turn off the two features

Tags: wi-fi

The WiFi feature and data connection in my tablet turns on automatically. After resetting, the problem goes away but as soon as I download programs that I need, the problem comes back. Anyone with suggestions?

Comment: Related: [Wifi and Data switching on automatically in my HTC Desire 820 device](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/120522)

Answer (score 2):

Either an app that you have given permission to [modify system settings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_SETTINGS) is doing this which should be easily solved by checking each of your apps permission settings?

...Or maybe you have something like WiFi "[Scanning Always Available](http://www.howtogeek.com/211186/how-to-disable-google-location-wi-fi-scanning-on-android/)"?

If you feel up to it, you may also find more information by looking at your Android's log files (either via an [app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376889/can-i-see-the-logcat-on-the-android-phone-itself-without-connecting-it-to-the-c) that can look at the logs or connecting a computer and using "adb logcat")